# vscode sorts hex filenames in an unexpected way

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the explorer view in Visual Studio code, I have a folder with files that are named with a long hexadecimal string.

The order they are sorted in is unexpected and undesirable in this case:

Expected sort order:

```
056e66b20944d4cb1ecbb1744d2851e6e3f89c80e9db3afff03b3fc1c1291768
292f9d21d38ac982d12ddc6f2a4953710b24291dafd72ad39b87babbb5aea87e
31282ddefe75bd65c535c89bbfe6c8c0046ee3c4457370fada08b006b286d3da
43480995c938409ad6423f40b3f2849ab3c726167ba739c886f971a7cb59b701
445c016c41e0197a8c0587a7bdc804370e31412e49c9bd80ba6baa0b67074d1c
4525d09abb29e3922f0897f7ea26d165cd6f2ebaeba322eb25af24aced613af1
4bae1011637c4c5e2de64ac5ce0966aaf91a44a12ccd12391deb60834bfdd77b
4e1962d7c8490870b4d10e270f997e663dddf2e9c0cb97cf0a137820ed576f10
4ea40d27a2cfcec3d38b2a0ebe5ca77633d27a394541c449b500fce4639516d4
523d612e9cd24c2fca3c4d97b340e89c7dc6bb326a9d75d5a0476f56680d06dc
59c7e095fd35a81ce5b97b10490bb4ee79ae10a003ed3e99f1c2523153b7446e
60cce3519052443b6eb66426edcfd7b395d8b97913e15256b77924964e8e6291
64b7ddb74f132147f5d52a6712acbe075ae6886aa59f2866b014cad187c5828a
65cdaa18192aee6f9c254882a3a7f4e57f28681ee263e9fd155fefcd6d9a7e7f
773030ff70cb880d96020ab23f0c27b77b9f83d0fc13086f7d676c9fc792d5d7
7b4ff8ad8c828f0855329495e1260f28de7fc1e828e3339b7dddc2d116d19742
856f6919674269f6b6ed9885db0fe162b58af8f434f50d6cf0acc9a611c50446
8fee6a1847b07f4933116726f66b9218dde8c59d1f7b94de92f9f0683571a362
9f6b0e2884bb2b82a3a452e4011d72c49e7ed45b310a408b51d0ca27ab259488
a4bcce19686277a3796057ee34746000857d9715702615f859bcdce2bc551a4d
a730d544a683436d540a39b86342c9a56348848dcd0b8f05af9f061b6df8d4ec
ac70c4411ef34b85e9e038bdd0e1c5fb4b27ce5be304cdb9479fe829e2ab9886
af4c2580c6c3e68236ce4f353c045f871e4780b85fdb54c00529426e09bc36ce
d10f0f0a1346301a869482ed07ac49dfec25f579f26f3e7a95337695f18e114a
e0c6aceb7b4ffa8a31e71d409d5f1d1c8ee341e4e320eea9d0fdcae2044480d3
e86a512b6f8ca231989fe68b97cb5b53a2da7df6e6aeb725a8a61e81bcd9922f
ecf48b6c1f4307f5c27c8cf883aaf1dfa2d1e23e68e2e83d24f151917f6ffb10
f9cebfa4ebc61616b4d770068a1c9c3f4c31a78dfb3b6fa5ba0b3a65b6ceee8b
```

Actual sort order [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXy2R.png) (transcribed below):

```
4bae1011637c4c5e2de64ac5ce0966aaf91a44a12ccd12391deb60834bfdd77b
4e1962d7c8490870b4d10e270f997e663dddf2e9c0cb97cf0a137820ed576f10
4ea40d27a2cfcec3d38b2a0ebe5ca77633d27a394541c449b500fce4639516d4
7b4ff8ad8c828f0855329495e1260f28de7fc1e828e3339b7dddc2d116d19742
8fee6a1847b07f4933116726f66b9218dde8c59d1f7b94de92f9f0683571a362
9f6b0e2884bb2b82a3a452e4011d72c49e7ed45b310a408b51d0ca27ab259488
056e66b20944d4cb1ecbb1744d2851e6e3f89c80e9db3afff03b3fc1c1291768
59c7e095fd35a81ce5b97b10490bb4ee79ae10a003ed3e99f1c2523153b7446e
60cce3519052443b6eb66426edcfd7b395d8b97913e15256b77924964e8e6291
64b7ddb74f132147f5d52a6712acbe075ae6886aa59f2866b014cad187c5828a
65cdaa18192aee6f9c254882a3a7f4e57f28681ee263e9fd155fefcd6d9a7e7f
292f9d21d38ac982d12ddc6f2a4953710b24291dafd72ad39b87babbb5aea87e
445c016c41e0197a8c0587a7bdc804370e31412e49c9bd80ba6baa0b67074d1c
523d612e9cd24c2fca3c4d97b340e89c7dc6bb326a9d75d5a0476f56680d06dc
856f6919674269f6b6ed9885db0fe162b58af8f434f50d6cf0acc9a611c50446
4525d09abb29e3922f0897f7ea26d165cd6f2ebaeba322eb25af24aced613af1
31282ddefe75bd65c535c89bbfe6c8c0046ee3c4457370fada08b006b286d3da
773030ff70cb880d96020ab23f0c27b77b9f83d0fc13086f7d676c9fc792d5d7
43480995c938409ad6423f40b3f2849ab3c726167ba739c886f971a7cb59b701
a4bcce19686277a3796057ee34746000857d9715702615f859bcdce2bc551a4d
a730d544a683436d540a39b86342c9a56348848dcd0b8f05af9f061b6df8d4ec
ac70c4411ef34b85e9e038bdd0e1c5fb4b27ce5be304cdb9479fe829e2ab9886
af4c2580c6c3e68236ce4f353c045f871e4780b85fdb54c00529426e09bc36ce
d10f0f0a1346301a869482ed07ac49dfec25f579f26f3e7a95337695f18e114a
e0c6aceb7b4ffa8a31e71d409d5f1d1c8ee341e4e320eea9d0fdcae2044480d3
e86a512b6f8ca231989fe68b97cb5b53a2da7df6e6aeb725a8a61e81bcd9922f
ecf48b6c1f4307f5c27c8cf883aaf1dfa2d1e23e68e2e83d24f151917f6ffb10
f9cebfa4ebc61616b4d770068a1c9c3f4c31a78dfb3b6fa5ba0b3a65b6ceee8b
```

As far as I can tell, they have been sorted with preferential treatment given to the the span of decimal digits [0-9] preceding the first alphabetic [a-f] character.  I presume this is to give files that are named with numbers a natural sort order for humans (e.g. to prevent 10.txt from appearing before 2.txt)?  But it obviously doesn't work in this case for hexadecimal filenames.

I've inserted spaces to show the span of characters that seems to control the sort order.

```
4  bae1011637c4c5e2de64ac5ce0966aaf91a44a12ccd12391deb60834bfdd77b
4  e1962d7c8490870b4d10e270f997e663dddf2e9c0cb97cf0a137820ed576f10
4  ea40d27a2cfcec3d38b2a0ebe5ca77633d27a394541c449b500fce4639516d4
7  b4ff8ad8c828f0855329495e1260f28de7fc1e828e3339b7dddc2d116d19742
8  fee6a1847b07f4933116726f66b9218dde8c59d1f7b94de92f9f0683571a362
9  f6b0e2884bb2b82a3a452e4011d72c49e7ed45b310a408b51d0ca27ab259488
056  e66b20944d4cb1ecbb1744d2851e6e3f89c80e9db3afff03b3fc1c1291768
59  c7e095fd35a81ce5b97b10490bb4ee79ae10a003ed3e99f1c2523153b7446e
60  cce3519052443b6eb66426edcfd7b395d8b97913e15256b77924964e8e6291
64  b7ddb74f132147f5d52a6712acbe075ae6886aa59f2866b014cad187c5828a
65  cdaa18192aee6f9c254882a3a7f4e57f28681ee263e9fd155fefcd6d9a7e7f
292  f9d21d38ac982d12ddc6f2a4953710b24291dafd72ad39b87babbb5aea87e
445  c016c41e0197a8c0587a7bdc804370e31412e49c9bd80ba6baa0b67074d1c
523  d612e9cd24c2fca3c4d97b340e89c7dc6bb326a9d75d5a0476f56680d06dc
856  f6919674269f6b6ed9885db0fe162b58af8f434f50d6cf0acc9a611c50446
4525  d09abb29e3922f0897f7ea26d165cd6f2ebaeba322eb25af24aced613af1
31282  ddefe75bd65c535c89bbfe6c8c0046ee3c4457370fada08b006b286d3da
773030  ff70cb880d96020ab23f0c27b77b9f83d0fc13086f7d676c9fc792d5d7
43480995  c938409ad6423f40b3f2849ab3c726167ba739c886f971a7cb59b701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```

And this example doesn't have enough names to show it, but it's actually doing something smarter, because if you just prefix all these filenames with `f` it still comes out in the wrong order.  So it seems to know how to lexicographically sort numbers in natural order regardless of where they appear in the string.  Whoever implemented this was clever, but not clever enough (too clever?) to correctly handle hex strings

Is there a way I can change that setting?  I have had a look through the settings in vscode and there are options for files vs folders (Explorer: Sort Order),  lexicographic options for upper or lower case (Explorer: Sort Order Lexicographic Options), but nothing to enable support for correct sorting of hex filenames.

I don't like this in this case because I usually try to spot the file by inspecting the first 2-4 characters of the name, but they're not sorting correctly so they're difficult to find.  And it's too much of a cognitive challenge for me to scan the string to locate the first [a-f] character to make sense of the sorting as it is.  So, I'm hoping there's a per-workspace setting, or a per-folder setting that I can adjust. Or some other way.

Comment: You said changing `Explorer: Sort Order Lexicographic Options` not worked but I tried and it worked. Is there a mistake I made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made some research and found a solution. Follow the below steps:

- Open your VS Code settings
- Type `Lexicographic`
- Change `Explorer: Sort Order Lexicographic Options` to `unicode`

[image]

You can also define this setting only for your workspace.